# How can I prove $\hat{a}^\dagger(\vec{k})$ is a complex scalar field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, klein-gordon-equation

I want to prove $\hat{a}^\dagger(\vec{k})$, the creation operator for real Klein-Gordon bosons transforms like a complex scalar field under Lorentz transformations, so
$$\exp\left\{-\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2\hbar}\omega^{\mu\nu}\hat{M}_{\mu\nu}\right\}\space\hat{a}^\dagger(\vec{k})\space\exp\left\{\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2\hbar}\omega^{\mu\nu}\hat{M}_{\mu\nu}\right\} = \hat{a}^\dagger(\Lambda\vec{k}),$$
and I'd like to do it, if possible, algebraically manipulating the left-hand side expression.

I thought maybe I could use a formula like
$$\mathrm{e}^{-\hat{A}}\hat{B}\space\mathrm{e}^\hat{A} = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{ad}(\hat{A})}\hat{B}$$
but I don't know how to get the adjoint representation of the (proper, orthochronous) Lorentz group as $\hat{M}_{\mu\nu}$ has two indicies and it makes it hard to see what the structure constants are (I do know the commutation relation of those, though).

Is this a good idea, or should I proceed in another way? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive the Lorentz transformation of the creation and annihilation operators, you can start with the transformation single particle states. For scalar particles, with appropriate normalization, you can have:
$$
U(\Lambda)|k\rangle=|\Lambda k\rangle
$$
On the other hand, by making use of the definition of the creation operator:
\begin{align}
U(\Lambda)|k\rangle=&U(\Lambda)a^\dagger(k)|0\rangle\\
=&U(\Lambda)a^\dagger(k)U^\dagger(\Lambda)U(\Lambda)|0\rangle\\
=&U(\Lambda)a^\dagger(k)U^\dagger(\Lambda)|0\rangle
\end{align}
From this, you can show that:
$$
U(\Lambda)a^\dagger(k)U^\dagger(\Lambda) = a^\dagger(\Lambda k)
$$

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'd upvote you but I only have a reputation of 1 :(
I had already thought of this procedure, though, my question tried to ask for a way to do it using the expression for $\hat{U}(\Lambda)$ that I give in it, the one with the exponential of the generators.

Comment: @PabloT. Well you can't proceed that way without knowing the commutation relations between the generators and $a^\dagger$. Normally one has to use the transformation properties of the states (equivalently of the creation and annihilation operators) to construct those $M_{\mu\nu}$ operators that can act as transformation generators, not the other way around. To manipulate the left hand side of that equation, you would need to know what is the operator  $M_{\mu\nu}$ in the Hilbert space.